# Implementation of user authentication while connecting to a remote Apache server over the Internet

Tags: java, apache, jsp, authentication, servlets

Can the authentication be achieved by simply implementing a generic Login page in JSP?
The purpose is to control access to content placed on the remote Apache server.
Any important points to take care of?
Please help.